# changing displayed value of ngOptions messes with the selected value in drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, ng-options

I implemented a functionality where a user can convert the showing list of  temperature values in a drop-down menu to Celsius and Fahrenheit respectively.

I'm using a **select** input with **ng-options** like this:

```
<select ng-model="thresshold.selected" ng-options="value as (showCelsius?value:side.convertTo(value, false)) for value in thresshold.values">
```

**showCelsius** is Boolean value. the predefined choice is **true**, as in shows Celsius, else shows Fahrenheit. convertTo is a function that accepts the temperature value and the **showCelsius** variable and converts to the desired temperature unit.

Initially the drop-down selected value(in Celsius) is displayed correctly. When i try to change to Fahrenheit the labels of the drop-down menu change as expected but when i try to switch back to Celsius the selected value is not displayed. Trying to interact with the drop-down menu shows that the values are correctly converted. Converting back to Fahrenheit re-displays the selected value in the **select**.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, your function convertTo(val, bool) :

```
 showCelsius?value:side.convertTo(value, false)
```

takes true / false as a parameter for either Celcius or fahrenheit. Should your code not read as follows?

```
showCelsius?value:side.convertTo(value, showCelsius)
```

Otherwise it will always show only the one option?

Comment: Thank you for your input and you are right that the second parameter should be showCelsius, but that doesn't affect the fact that the **value** after converting to Fahrenheit and then back to Celsius is not displayed in the drop-down box.

Comment: Perhaps you need to check the attributes of your your object, and how the selected value is set. See the docs here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions with the link to an example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qWzTb/

Comment: No, that's not the case either. The **threshold** is an object yes, but with the attribute **values** which is an **array** of values and where **select** options are defined from. I already searched angular docs thoroughly for a hint, but with no luck.